# jQuery 1.7.2 \IE9 ajax Invocation Not Clearing Discarded Elements

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I've been wrestling with the following issue for most of the day and have made absolutely zero headway so thought i'd reach out to see if anybody has some ideas (help!!!).  I'm currently using jQuery 1.7.2 in conjunction with IE9 and am invoking a simple $.ajax call which simply retrieves some HTML.  The HTML is subsequently inserted into a div as follows:

`$("#viewContent").html(content);`

the complete relevant jQuery code is shown below:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: loadUrl, 
    type: "GET", 
    cache: false, 
    data: {command: "loadView", recordid: contextId}, 
    dataType: "html", 
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        getViewManager().setMode("ERROR");
        handleError(xhr.status, thrownError);
        $("#viewContent").parent().removeClass("ajaxLoading");  
    }           
});
request.done(onLoadViewSuccess);

var onLoadViewSuccess = function(content) {
    $("#viewContent").parent().removeClass("ajaxLoading");
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
        $("#viewContent").html(content);    
    }               
    content = null;      
}
```

Now as to the issue, you'll notice i've inserted the content 100 times, the for loop is intended only to exaggerate the climbing memory (observed via Drip memory profiler for IE) which climbs (along with the total number of DOM nodes retained by IE).  The content isn't an issue as I replaced it with a static empty  string and it does the same thing within the onLoadViewSuccess 
function:

```
var onLoadViewSuccess = function(content) {
    $("#viewContent").parent().removeClass("ajaxLoading");
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
        $("#viewContent").html("<div/>");   
    }               
    content = null;      
}
```

i.e. Drip will show 100 new DOM nodes after each ajax call and steadily climbing memory.  Now as to why this appears to be something up with the ajax call, if I call the same method on the initial page load:

`$(document).ready(function() {onLoadViewSuccess("<div/>")});`

I don't see the same behavior (i.e. invoking html("<div/>") each iteration within the for loop is properly clearing the replaced DOM node within IE9 as opposed to creating 100 new ones and keeping them all in memory...I've reviewed several reported issues with IE and jQuery's ajax functionality, but the only topics which come close appear to be related to older IE versions which have since been addressed in previous versions of jQuery...

I suspect i'm missing something fundamental as this seems to be such a trivial use-case and typically when I can't find any similar topics via google, 9 out of 10 times its due to something foolish on my part...

Comment: I forgot to add, Chrome and FF are not showing the same behavior (of course)

Answer (score 0):

So I believe i've gotten to the bottom of the issue...After a painful process of elimination, it turns out IE was not cleaning up elements associated with a particular CSS class I had defined:

```
.shadow {
border-collapse: separate; 
-moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 6px 3px #777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 3px #777;   
box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 4px;   
**behavior: url(/btms/resources/css/PIE.htc);**
position: relative;
}
```

The behavior value was the issue (no longer used but inadvertently left in when I was originally developing the application to support IE 8 - ironically PIE is intended to add CSS3 support for IE 8 but in this case somehow ties an IE 9 recognized reference to any elements associated with the class preventing IE from freeing up those element resources even after being removed via jQuery).  Hopefully this post saves someone else the same agony\frustration...